# Getting list of running processes on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, terminal

I am essentially looking for the iOS equivalent of

```
adb shell ps
```

On android this returns to me a list of all apps running on my emulator. For iOS things seem to be a bit more complicated as it looks like it is not supported. Some of the solutions listed here suggest installing a cydia package named adv-cmds which has the command i am looking for but I believe cydia is not meant for simulators.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Command to find list of running apps and their pid for iOS simulator is

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted launchctl print system
```